# Node.js loop over variable and print it's values

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to loop over the following variable and print out it's values (0,1,2)
i've tried to run forEach on it, but i get an error that forEach is not a function.

```
let colors = {
RED: 0,
GREEN: 1,
BLUE: 2 };
```

Comment: yes there is a way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Depending on what you mean by _"print out it's values"_, you might want to just use `console.dir`

Comment: I found an answer in How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var colorKeys = Object.keys(colors);

for(int i = 0; i < colorKeys.length; i++){
    console.log(colors[colorKeys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: This is printing out the keys (RED, GREEN, BLUE) i want to print the values (0, 1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
let colors = {
RED: 0,
GREEN: 1,
BLUE: 2 }; 

for(let i in colors){
console.log(colors[i]);
}
```